# Mingw cross compilation only runs in debug mode linux -> windows

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, cross-platform

My c++ application is being built on a debian server using the mingw-w64 cross compilation toolchain. The artifact that is created from that build works great when all the msys2 dependencies are present, however only the debug build. The release build starts a process, waits for a while and closes it without printing or prompting anything.

The build is done using CMake and my cross compilation specific section looks like this:

```
if ("${CROSS_COMPILE}" STREQUAL "1")
    MESSAGE("Cross compile")
    SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
    include(CMakeForceCompiler)
    IF ("${GNU_HOST}" STREQUAL "")
        SET(GNU_HOST i586-mingw32msvc)
    ENDIF ()
    SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${GNU_HOST}-gcc)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${GNU_HOST}-g++)
    SET(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${GNU_HOST}-windres)
    SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/${GNU_HOST})
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
    add_definitions(-DUSE_CROSS_COMPILE)
    add_definitions(-Bstatic)
ENDIF ()
```

And it is called like this in debug/release mode:

```
cmake -DGNU_HOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32 -DCROSS_COMPILE=1 ..
cmake -DGNU_HOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32 -DCROSS_COMPILE=1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

I can of course provide much more information about my CMakeLists.txt, however I am not exactly sure which parts make the most sense.

I am using the following libraries, that are present during compilation (copied from my windows msys2 installation):

- OpenGL
- GTK-3.0
- GTK-Sourceview-3.0
- Threads (via `find_package(Threads)`)

Does anyone have an idea why the debug mode works without any issue while the release mode wont properly start my application?

**EDIT**
The following line is working in debug mode but not in release mode:

```
std::ifstream is("settings.conf", std::ios::in);
```

It is throwing a SIGSEGV in release mode, but works in debug mode

Comment: Maybe your code has some Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I guess there is no easy way to debug that even if the first instruction in main fails, right? (static initializers, etc)

Comment: i stand corrected, this instruction is running, I was not using the correct binary, that means it should be possible to narrow down the offending part of the code

Comment: So what is the close reason, how does the call stack look at exit? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: i am working on that isolating the offending part and then updating my question

Comment: The issue seems to be in `ifstream`, seems strange, that should normally work id think